# parsing textarea input

Tags: python, html, parsing, textarea

so i have an html textarea that gives me user input data of the following form:

```
>Blabhb blabhab blabhahb etc etc 
AJSAKLFALELKNELNEFLKJELKJAELFKJLKEJFLKJF
LAKEFLKJAEFLKJELAJELFJLAEJFAENFANELFJEFJ
EKAFNEFNJEKJKEEKFKEAKJFKEJAFKJKEAJAEJFKJ
EFAA
```

and in order to only use everything after the first line, and have it all joined as one series of letters without spaces or returns, i have written this up:

```
data_lines = data.split('\n')
data_lines = data_lines[1:]
data_lines = ''.join(data_lines)
```

but i am still getting a few spaces and can't seem to put my finger on why.  can anyone help me or maybe optimize this method? i'd like to end up with one long string of letters.

looking at the source code of the output shows a continuous string of letters like i want, but it doesn't display that way on the screen.

thanks

Comment: What are you doing to get the `textarea` in the first place? eg it's come from a form submission? or it's from a file... etc...

Comment: What happens when you do `data_lines = ''.join(data.splitlines()[1:])` ?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
data_lines = data.split('\r\n')
```

Comment: Does it matter if this is done in DOS/Windows or on Unix? In other words, does the program need to know the environment it's running in or can you use `\r\n` in both environments?

Comment: it's running on a unix server, but should be universal, i guess.

Comment: Using '\r\n' as the parameter to split means that it will split on any combination of '\r' or '\n'.

Comment: i tried the '\r\n' and it didn't change the output.  it's still not united as one string.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need to remove new lines here's the simple code:

```
data_lines = data.replace('\n', '')
print(data_lines)
```